# Is it possible for my app to revoke an OAuth token it no longer needs?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an app that goes through the normal OAuth 2 flow and uses the received tokens to do the usual API calls on behalf of the users.  When they turn that feature off, I'd like to revoke the token (partly because I don't want it sitting around on general principles, and partly because I just saw an exciting bug where an automated process didn't "get the memo" and kept acting on a user's behalf even when they no longer wanted that behavior).

Is it possible to revoke a Microsoft OAuth token in a manner similar to the way Google does [Revoke Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a programmatic way to revoke an Access Token, however, these tokens [expire after 1 hour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#token-lifetimes). So as long as your application destroys its cached token it should take care of itself.

A User can revoke an application they've consented too via https://myapps.microsoft.com. The exception being that if the application was consented to on their behalf by an Admin.

Comment: I'm caching the refresh token, so that's what I'd want to revoke. Though your reply does suggest a mitigation strategy: I could have my primary app hold the refresh token and only supply access tokens to the dependent service. Hmm. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, refresh tokens are a little different. This isn't a bad strategy. There is also a beta `user/{id}/invalidateAllRefreshTokens` method by this is a massive hammer. It _isn't_ app specific.

Comment: You could also _use_ the refresh token but disregard the result. That way you're previously cached refresh token is no longer valid.